# how can i find even and odd number between any number?

Tags: java

i was making a program as a training for my learning in java which can view even and odd numbers between any numbers that the user have entered , the problem that if i entered an even number at start it would show me the message

> you haven't entered an even number

i just want him to view this message at first if the user have entered an odd number at start

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  isevennumber(1, 5);
}

public static void isevennumber(int startwith, int endwith) {

    for (int i = startwith; i <= endwith; i++) {

        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("you have entered an even number which is " + i);

        } else  {
            System.out.println("you haven't entered an even number");

        }
    }

}
```

the output is

`you haven't entered an even number
you have entered an even number which is 2
you haven't entered an even number
you have entered an even number which is 4
you haven't entered an even number`

sorry for any mistake , this is my first post here

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: It's not clear how you want this program to behave, please clarify the question and provide an example of correct behaviour given the input.

Comment: there is no code to read the user input

Comment: There are a few things wrong here, although it's not entirely clear what you want to do. My advice would be to try to break the problem down into smaller parts instead of trying to do it all at once, and, to understand your code, try to put into words what your code is doing (your loop = "For each number between start and end, ..."). Start off by figuring out how to get input from the user. Then check whether that number is even. At this point you shouldn't have written a loop yet, because you haven't gotten to that step yet, so it should be clear that that part shouldn't be inside the loop.

Comment: Unrelated to your question; but, you should start using camel case for function and variable names. `isEvenNumber` is a lot easier to read compared to `isevennumber`; because, each separate word is indicated by the capitalized letter. If not camel case; then, use an proper naming convention. For things like classes you would use pascal case. `MyClass` instead of `myClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one more `if` to check whether this is first iteration or not:

```
public static void isevennumber(int startwith, int endwith) {
    for (int i = startwith; i <= endwith; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            System.out.println("you have entered an even number which is " + i);
        else if (i == startwith)
            System.out.println("you haven't entered an even number");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that every time in your loop that the number isn't odd it will print you haven't entered an even number.

You can try like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    isevennumber(1, 5);
  }

  public static void isevennumber(int startwith, int endwith) {
      List<Integer> evenNumbers = new ArrayList();
      for (int i = startwith; i <= endwith; i++) {
          if (i % 2 == 0) {
              evenNumbers.add(i);
          }
      }

      if (evenNumbers.isEmpty()) {
          System.out.println("you haven't entered an even number");
          return;
      }
      System.out.println("you have entered the following even numbers " + evenNumbers);
  }
```

This will print out:

```
 you have entered the following even numbers [2, 4]
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing one step, problem here is that every time in your loop that the number isn't odd it will print you haven't entered an even number.

Below is the correct solution for you.

```
    public static void isevennumber(int startwith, int endwith) {
        for (int i = startwith; i <= endwith; i++) 
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
            System.out.println("you have entered an even number which is " + i);
            }            
            else if (i == startwith)
            {
                System.out.println("you haven't entered an even number");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate answer!